# Trigger an AWS lambda after an event is completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there anyway by which I can trigger a lambda once an event is completed (After the completion of DMS Task events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive Database Migration Service [event notifications via SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/events-and-notifications-in-aws-database-migration-service/). You can then [configure SNS to trigger Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html) and there are [instructions for subscribing to DMS event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Events.html#CHAP_Events.Subscription).

Comment: Thanks for your update. I found that if I can subscribe for 'state change'  Replication task events to get notified for task start or failure ,I did not find a SNS to trigger to notify 'Task Complete' status.
Any way to know if the replication task is completed ?